# Which is faster: Assigning same value to a variable, or finding out if it is already set?

Tags: c++, memory, conditional-statements

This is probably inconsequential with today's computing power, but it's something that interests me nontheless.

I have an array of booleans, which are changed on each iteration of main loop depending on key pressed. This array is then referenced for info about keyboard input.

So: is it more effective to check if the variable is already set to the same value before writing to it,

```
void keyDown(unsigned char key){
    if(!keys[key])
        keys[key] = true;
}
```

or is it better to just write the value to the corresponding array field on each KeyDown function iteration?

```
void keyDown(unsigned char key){
    keys[key] = true;
}
```

Thanx .)

Comment: one access versus 2, and no branch, the second version should be faster. the first version has a bug

Comment: My intuition says that just assigning is faster because you avoid the branch, but you have to actually time this.

Comment: @sp2danny: so accessing and writing takes more or less same time? actually makes sense...

Comment: @Kuro second statement is obviously faster than the first,because you avoid one comparison!Check it on your own with a t_clock :)

Comment: @ThemisBeris: you are only considering instructions, not memory accesses. Memory accesses are typically a lot more expensive that instruction cycles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't matter. We're talking about a callback function here that is executed every time the user hits a key. That isn't going to happen millions of times per second.

That said, the branchless version which just assigns the value is probably going to be faster. And more importantly, it has a WTF factor of 0. My first reaction to the conditional version was "WTF is this shit?"

Comment: hmm... now that i think of it, the keyDown function isn't invoked very often. that's the reason I have to be solving it by putting the values of pressed keys into an array, and setting them to false on keyUp. thanks for making me think :)

Comment: concerning the WTF factor: i never did it conditionaly before, but i tend to overthink stuff, and it is something that's been bothering me since my first keyobard input handling some 10 years ago .)

Comment: Also, on any non-trivial system, the I/O interrupt, driver, signaling to make thread ready, message-handling etc. will totally swamp such micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Writing to a variable only requires a single CPU instruction. A conditional statement requires a comparison and jump at best (unless the compiler optimizes it out). At worst, the statement used for a condition might require several instructions to evaluate.

Comment: Bot note that a read from memory typically generates one bus cycle whereas a write typically generate two, so the cost of the additional compare and branch instructions has to be traded off against the cost of the additional bus cycle. Hence the answer will be architecture-dependent, but on modern CPUs the processor is usually a *lot* faster than memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you check if it's already set you'll probably not gain anything due to it having to do the check (Thinking about the amount of instructions compared to not doing the check). If you had more than one things to do if it were set then you'd get some gain from checking.

When your not checking it just do it anyway which will be faster because of the lesser amount of instructions

Answer (score 1):

I would be more concerned about using the correct containers, for example if doing a lot of push_back calls use a list instead of vector.
These sorts of optimizations make sense, an if condition within a function called rarely in the scope of cpu cycles is probably not worth spending too much time considering.